# How to install Insightops(log-entries ) Agent on ubuntu container

Tags: docker, logentries

I am trying to install and setup insightops(log-entries) Linux agent in Docker to use log-entries agent in the container

Adding the Dockerfile-

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y
COPY Linux_Insight_Agent/ /app/
RUN chmod u+x /app/agent_installer.sh
RUN ./app/agent_installer.sh install_start
```

at the time of build the image it is throwing me the error -------------------------------------------

```
Installing systemd service [INFO]
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/ir_agent.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/ir_agent.service, pointing to /etc/systemd/system/ir_agent.service.
```

Please anyone can help me on this and suggest me some another way if required to setup it on docker container.

NOTE: I don't want to use insightops(log-entries) docker agent.

Document followed: https://insightops.help.rapid7.com/v1.0/docs/insight-agent-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem we need to add privileged flag for Full container capabilities and start init process on the container

Adding docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
#To start init process in container on runtime
ENTRYPOINT  ["/sbin/init"]
COPY ./Linux_Insight_Agent/Linux_Insight_Agent
RUN chmod -R 755 /Linux_Insight_Agent
#Install and start the Agent on container
RUN /Linux_Insight_Agent/agent_installer.sh install
RUN /Linux_Insight_Agent/agent_installer.sh start
```

Compose file:

```
 version: "2" 
    services:
      le:
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: test-le:latest
        privileged: true
        restart: always
        volumes:
         - /var/log:/rest/out
```

Build and run the Image using below command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

It will restart the container with running Linux agent in the container